# Disable IIS Request Filtering for certain paths

Tags: iis, iis-7, requestfiltering

Is there any way I can have IIS 7.0+ (or 7.5+) configured such that for certain paths Request Filtering is completely disabled. That is,

```
http://host.local/foo/bar.cs
```

is forbidden (since serving `*.cs` files is explicitly forbidden in `applicationHost.config`), but

```
http://host.local/foo/allow-all/bar.cs
```

is allowed.

Answer (score 5):

In your `allow-all` directory, you can create a web.config file with the following configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <remove fileExtension=".cs" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".cs" mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This configuration removes the `.cs` extension from the request filtering. Additionally, for IIS to properly serve content, it needs a MIME type, so the `.cs` extension is added as text/plain.

These changes will also apply to all child directories of `allow-all`. This configuration works with an Integrated App Pool. Classic may require additional changes since there are HTTP handlers that explicitly disallow .cs as well.

Comment: That's nice, but I do not have an `/allow-all` path per se: it is a dynamic URL handled by the ASP.NET MVC Routing. Is this possible under these circumstances.

Comment: @Anton If it's dynamic, then better try serving them yourself -- create url rewriting rule to some script that will read and send content of the requested file into a browser. I'm just unsure if URL rewriting module is executed before or after request filtering -- I think after (for real/existing files) but that may not be the case for non-existing URLs.

Comment: @LazyOne the URL rewriting seems to happen after the request filtering.  Or, at least the custom handler I installed was choking until I added a <clear /> in my filters for the path in question.